# Determine whether the linear transformation T is one-to-one, onto or neither.

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine whether the linear transformation $T$ is one-to-one, onto or neither.

$T$ : P → P defined by $T(p(x)) = p'(x)$

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with the definitions of the terms used here?

Comment: Calculate $T(x)$ and $T(x + 2)$.

Comment: You should clarify what $P$ is as well... is it the space of all polynomials of any finite degree?  Or is it defined in an earlier question?  Have you taken integral calculus before?

Comment: I think that the question should be asking given the derivative of an arbitrary polynomial, are there any different polynomials that give the same derivative? And no haven't take integral calculus yet

Comment: Yes, for example $p(x)=x^2$ and $p(x)=x^2+2$ have the same derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you will be able to answer this question if a someone is willing to explain the terminology:

- What the phrase "*one-to-one*" means.
- What is the big capital letter $P$
- What the word "*onto*" means.
- etc...

#### What is the big capital letter $P$?

Answer: $P$ is the set of all polynomials.

#### What is a polynomial?

Some example of polynomials are shown below:

- $f(x) = 56.4*x^9 16.78*x^4 + x + 99.1$
- $g(x) = 5*x^3 16.78*x^2 + x + 1.6$
- $h(x) = \pi*x^100$
- $i(x) = \pi$
- $j(x) = 0$
- $k(x) = x$

Unlike most mathematicians, I find *definition by example* to be very useful.

A polynomial is an function similar to $5*x^{3}+x+{8}$ (no sine functions, just $x$ raised to some power)

#### What Do *One-to-One* and *Onto* mean?

Suppose that you have a machine.

There is a set of valid inputs to the machine.

There is a set of valid outputs to the machine.

[image: CARTOON OF A FUNCTION MACHINE HAVING AN INPUT FUNNEL AND AN OUTPUT]

Suppose that the only inputs allowed into the machine are $-2$, $-1$, $0$ , $+1$ and $+2$

Get out a pieces of paper. Rotate the paper sideways, and draw a vertical-line in the middle of the paper so that the paper is chopped into two halves.

Draw each input to the machine to the left of the line.

Draw each output to the machine to the right of the line.

[image: diagram of inputs and outputs]

An input-output machine is "***one-to-one***" when every output-dot has zero or one line shooting out of it.

If the machine is $(x^2)$, then note that inputs $-2$ and $+2$ have the same output $+4$. Thus, the $(x^2)$ machine is **NOT** "*one-to-one*."

The phrasing "*one-to-one*" comes from a kind of implicit assumption that every dot in the inputs has exactly one line coming out of it. When that's true, each dot on the input is matched to exactly one dot in the output. It's a very one-to-one relationship.

An example of a one-to-one relationship would be the married couples in a village, provided that:

- every husband have at most one wife.
- every wife has at most one husband.
- everyone is married

  - there are no bachelors or bachelorettes
  - there are no single men or single women

#### What does "*Onto" mean?

The diagram of dots and lines is onto if every dot on the right has at least one line coming out of it.

A machine with inputs and outputs is "***onto***" when, for any output, there is at least one input which produces that output.

For example, an older-style vending machine might match number-letter combinations (such as **4E**) to soda pop. Suppose there was a soda (e.g. Dr. Pepper) such that there was no letter-number code (or button) that a customer could enter to get that brand of soda pop. That would be a problem. Nobody would ever buy it. The soda would sit inside of the machine for years until they replaced the machine with one that has a touch screen interface with pictures instead of letter and numbers.

#### The Derivative

In your comments, you said that you have not taken calculus.

So, you probably do not know what a derivative is.

Note that the *derivative* of $x^{p}$  is $x^{(p-1)}$

- Multiply the new thing by the old exponent.
- Subtract one from the old exponent to get the new exponent.

For example, the derivative of $2*x^{7}$ is $2*7x^{6}$

If you have a lot of stuff added together, then take the derivative of each piece and then add the pieces together.

$$\mathtt{DERIVATIVE}(8*x^2 + 3*x^{100}) = 16*x + 300*x^{99}$$

#### Anti-Derivatives

The ***anti-derivative*** undoes taking the derivative.

There many $\mathtt{ANTI-DERIVATIVES}$ of $(x^{p})$.
Usually, $\left( \dfrac{x^{(p+1)}}{p+1} + c \right)$ is the anti-derivative of $(x^{p})$,
where $c$ is any old number, such as $25$ or $31.662$

The anti-derivative is the opposite of the derivative.

The one exception is $p = -1$. In that case, $x^p = \dfrac{1}{x}$

If $p = -1$, the derivative of $x^p$ is $\log(\vert x \vert)$

#### Reminder: What was your Homework Question

Determine whether the linear transformation $T$ is one-to-one, onto or neither.

$T: P → P$ defined by $T(p) = p′$
For any polynomial $p$, $T(p)$ is the derivative of $p$

#### Rewording your Homework Exercise

The derivative transformation is "*one-to-one*" if (and only if) there do not exist two different polynomials $p$ and $q$ such that $p′$ is the derivative of $p$ and $p^{\prime}$ is the derivative of $q$

Is the  derivative transformation "*one-to-one*"?

> Hint for "*one-to-one*":
>   The derivative of any constant (e.g. $1$, $2$ or $\pi$) is zero.
>   An anti-derivative of $0$ is any old constant number, such as $59$

Also, you are being asked if, for any polynomial $p^{\prime}$, is there at least one polynomial $p$ such that the derivative of $p$ is $p^{\prime}$? If so, then the derivative transformation is "*onto*"

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation ! I get what the question wants now